# Join table to subquery on another table and then sort the results

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I am new here and I would greatly appreciate some help with a problem that I have been struggling with all day.

Consider these 2 tables:

```
         albums (pkey: id)    years (pkey: album_id, year)

         id   genre_id       album_id  year
         ---  --------       --------  ---- 
         450      1           450      2000
         451      1           450      2001
         452      1           450      2002
         453      2           451      2005
         454      3           451      2012
                              452      1998
```

It may seem strange, but please assume that a single album can be associated with multiple years.

I want to select all albums in genre 1, sorted by the latest year of each of those albums. (Assume is is possible to sort by year).

So, I want this result:

```
 id    year
-----  ----
 451   2012
 450   2002
 452   1998
```

This is where I am at...

Obviously, I need to join the tables before ordering the results:

```
SELECT      id, year
FROM        albums INNER JOIN years ON albums.id = years.album_id
WHERE       genre_id = 1
ORDER BY    year;
```

This selects every year record for each album in genre 1, instead of only the latest year record for each album in genre 1.

Somehow, I need to incorporate a sub query, like this, to limit the years joined to the album table, to only the *latest year for that album*, and then sort again:

```
SELECT year FROM years WHERE album_id = ??? ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   album_id, max(year) latest
FROM albums INNER JOIN years ON id = album_id
WHERE genre_id = 1
GROUP BY album_id
ORDER BY latest DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be quite simple:

```
SELECT album_id, MAX(year) 
  FROM years
 GROUP BY album_id
 ORDER BY MAX(year) DESC;
```

Aggregate function `max()` allows you to select the latest year. Since you're using aggregate function, you also need a `group by` clause.

If you only need albums of a certain genre, just add `join` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is

```
select
a.id,
( 
   select max(b.year) from years b where a.id = b.album_id
) as year
from 
albums a
where genre_id = 1
order by year
```